# Copy and paste board

Tags: automation, clipboard

Idea:
Have a window that is always on top. 
Inside the window there are 10/20 text fields.
You can edit the fields in each individual box.
Once defined they become buttons.
When you click on a button it simply copies the text to clipboard.
When you click on a different button it copies that text instead.

Not overly complicated but is there anything like this that exists?
If not how difficult can a 0experiance coder make this?

Answer (score 1):

can be done like this:

open a new excel sheet, make the window on top, enter lines you want to use, bring windowsize down until only cells are shown with text you want to paste.

if you want to paste text in another window: select cell, move cusror to border of cell until move cursor emerges, drag and drop.